# Dynamic programming gives different result with cache implementation

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm doing a dynamic programming algorithm and after hopelessly debugging my program all evening I'm all out of answers. Basically my program returns the wrong answer when I use a cache for storing intermediate results. Here is my program:

```
def cachecost(cache, i, j, seq1, seq2):
    if cache[i][j] is None:
        v1 = v2 = v3 = v4 = None

        if i > 0 and j > 0:
            v1 = cachecost(cache, i-1, j-1, seq1, seq2) + 5
        if i > 0 and j >= 0:
            v2 = cachecost(cache, i-1, j, seq1, seq2) + 1
        if i >= 0 and j > 0:
            v3 = cachecost(cache, i, j-1, seq1, seq2) + 1
        if i == 0 and j == 0:
            v4 = 0

        cache[i][j] = max(v1, v2, v3, v4)
    return cache[i][j]


def cost(cache, i, j, seq1, seq2):
    v1 = v2 = v3 = v4 = None

    if i > 0 and j > 0:
        v1 = cost(cache, i-1, j-1, seq1, seq2) + 5
    if i > 0 and j >= 0:
        v2 = cost(cache, i-1, j, seq1, seq2) + 1
    if i >= 0 and j > 0:
        v3 = cost(cache, i, j-1, seq1, seq2) + 1
    if i == 0 and j == 0:
        v4 = 0

    cache[i][j] = max(v1, v2, v3, v4)
    return max(v1, v2, v3, v4)


def main():
    seq1 = 'AATAAT'
    seq2 = 'AAGG'
    cache = [[None] * (len(seq2) + 1)] * (len(seq1) + 1)
    cachescore = cachecost(cache, len(seq1), len(seq2), seq1, seq2)
    score = cost(cache, len(seq1), len(seq2), seq1, seq2)
    print 'Score without cache: %s, score with cache: %s' % (cachescore, score)


# Handle command line execution
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The algorithm basically calculates a `i * j` table through recursion where the cache implementation assures that each entry in the table is only calculated once.

Running the program produces the following output:

```
Score without cache: 36, score with cache: 22
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem is in this line

```
cache = [[None] * (len(seq2) + 1)] * (len(seq1) + 1)
```

It first creates a list of `None`s of size `len(seq2) + 1` and then another list of size `len(seq1) + 1` is created with all elements being the reference to the same `None`s list. So, if you are changing any of them, the change will be refelected in all others as well. For example,

```
lists = [[None] * 2] * 3
print lists
# [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
lists[0][1] = 1
print lists
# [[None, 1], [None, 1], [None, 1]]
```

So, you need to create it like this

```
cache = [[None] * (len(seq2) + 1) for _ in range(len(seq1) + 1)]
```

Now, on each iteration, a new list of `None`s will be created and all of them will be put together in a new list.

```
lists = [[None] * 2 for _ in range(3)]
print lists
# [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
lists[0][1] = 1
print lists
# [[None, 1], [None, None], [None, None]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: Gee, you've gotta be quick around here. :) Nice answer, thefourtheye.

Comment: @soren.qvist : For further info with cute diagrams, see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO member Ned Batchelder.